# Is it considered haram to be employed by a company that sells devices used to test Cannabis?

Tags: halal-haram

The company in question specializes in selling devices that measure the percentage of various ingredients like CBD and THC in Cannabis. As consuming Cannabis with THC is considered haram, the concern is whether working for such a company would also be considered haram.